# How to safely get an immutable byte slice from a `&mut [u32]`?

Tags: rust, unsafe

In a rather low level part of a project of mine, a function receives a mutable slice of primitive data (`&mut [u32]` in this case). This data should be written to a writer in little endian.

Now, this alone wouldn't be a problem, but all of this has to be fast. I measured my application and identified this as one of the critical paths. In particular, if the endianness doesn't need to be changed (since we're already on a little endian system), there shouldn't be any overhead.

This is my code ([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=8c87ec453e0a255c723f7a20fab1e290)):

```rust
use std::{io, mem, slice};

fn write_data(mut w: impl io::Write, data: &mut [u32]) -> Result<(), io::Error> {
    adjust_endianness(data);

    // Is this safe?
    let bytes = unsafe {
        let len = data.len() * mem::size_of::<u32>();
        let ptr = data.as_ptr() as *const u8;
        slice::from_raw_parts(ptr, len)
    };

    w.write_all(bytes)
}

fn adjust_endianness(_: &mut [u32]) {
    // implementation omitted
}
```

`adjust_endianness` changes the endianness in place (which is fine, since a wrong-endian `u32` is garbage, but still a valid `u32`).

This code works, but the critical question is: **Is this safe?** In particular, at some point, `data` and `bytes` both exist, being one mutable and one immutable slice to the same data. That sounds very bad, right?

On the other hand, I can do this:

```rust
let bytes = &data[..];
```

That way, I also have those two slices. The difference is just that `data` is now borrowed.

**Is my code safe or does it exhibit UB? Why? If it's not safe, how to safely do what I want to do?**

Comment: maybe https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.align_to https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=29ed3775cc87d01504624d2e94cc45f3 ?

Comment: Seeing as there is no definitive specification of behavior for `unsafe` Rust, it seems an answer could demonstrate unsafety but could not demonstrate safety.

Comment: I think you're in the clear, because `bytes` is derived from `data` -- it's not that different from just doing `let foo = &*data`, which also gives you a `&` slice from a `&mut` slice. Whether one can prove that is sound according to Rust's execution model, I'm not sure.

Comment: Why is it a mut slice in the first place? As trentcl already mentioned, it is more reasonable to think about turning one immutable slice to another immutable slice: a `&[u32]` into a `&[u8]`.

Comment: @E_net4 It's mutable because the endianness should be changed in-place. That way we can make sure to call `write_all` only once. With as much data as possible.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Yeah, I worried that would be a problem :/ We really need the unsafe code guidelines. Soon.

Comment: My suspicion is that you do indeed need to have `let bytes = &data[..];` before casting to a raw pointer. In particular, your cast to a raw pointer drops the lifetime, and allows your `&mut [u32]` to alias with an `&[u8]`, and that _seems_ like UB to me. It would be nice to get @RalfJung's take on this.

Comment: @BurntSushi5: Is it still UB if you don't use data as mutable in the lifespan of the derived pointer :) ? I would have intuitively say that it's fine because "time-wise" there's no overlap.

Comment: Don't know. My guess would be "yes," but that's mostly just me being conservative. Having `let bytes = &data[..];` before the raw pointer cast feels like it puts this pretty firmly in "that's safe" territory.

Comment: My $0.02:  See Rob Pike's classic blog post [The Byte Order Fallacy](https://commandcenter.blogspot.com/2012/04/byte-order-fallacy.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, creation of slices that violate Rust's safety rules, even briefly, is unsafe. If you cheat the borrow checker and make independent slices borrowing the same data as `&` and `&mut` at the same time, it will make Rust specify incorrect aliasing information in LLVM, and this may lead to actually miscompiled code. [Miri](https://github.com/rust-lang/miri) doesn't flag this case, because you're not using `data` afterwards, but the exact details of what is unsafe [are still being worked out](https://github.com/rust-lang/unsafe-code-guidelines).

To be safe, you should to explain the sharing situation to the borrow checker:

```rust
let shared_data = &data[..];
```

`data` will be temporarily reborrowed as shared/read-only for the duration `shared_data` is used. In this case it shouldn't cause any limitations. The `data` will keep being mutable after exiting this scope.

Then you'll have `&[u32]`, but you need `&[u8]`. Fortunately, *this* conversion is safe to do, because both are shared, and `u8` has lesser alignment requirement than `u32` (if it was the other way, you'd have to use [`align_to`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.align_to)!).

```rust
let shared_data = &data[..];
let bytes = unsafe {
    let len = shared_data.len() * mem::size_of::<u32>();
    let ptr = data.as_ptr() as *const u8;
    slice::from_raw_parts(ptr, len)
};
```

Comment: I've missed the `u32` twist the first time. Updated answer.